# ERC-20 Token Gas Fees

Tags: gas, gas-price

I have been researching gas fees, but there is one thing I have not figured out; and that is "Are the gas fees the same regardless of the amount of ERC-20 token I am trying to move around?" For example, I have X amount of ERC-20 token that I am trying to move between two wallets. The gas fee for this transaction is ~$50. During the same time, if I attempt to move 100X of another ERC-20 token, the gas fee is the same. So the question is, does it cost the same whether you send 100 dollar or 10,000 worth token?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the token, ERC-20 token can do anything in their transfer function.

For example there is popular "SafeMoon" type of tokens that under some circumstances it will interact with a pool causing a rebalancing which is more expensive that a simple transfer.